# Problems on testing middleware in Laravel with Clousure $next

Tags: testing, laravel-5, phpunit, middleware, laravel-middleware

I have this middleware on my app that checks the user role for a route:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{
   if (in_array($request->user()->rol, $roles)) {
        return $next($request);
   } else {
        return redirect()->action('SecurityController@noAutorizado');
   }
}
```

And I'm triying to make a test for this middleware (phpUnit):

```
    public function testUsuarioLogadoPuedeAccederAPantallaUsuarios()
{

    $user = UsuariosTestFixtures::unAsignador();
    $this->actingAs($user);
    $request = Request::create('/usuarios', 'GET');

    $middleware = new CheckRole();
    $response = $middleware->handle($request,Closure $next,$user->getRole(), function () {});
    $this->assertEquals($response, true);

}
```

But i'm retreiving this error: *Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::handle() must be an instance of Closure, null given*

I don't know how I have to pass the "Closure $next" on the $middleware->handle

I've tryed this:

```
public function testUsuarioLogadoPuedeAccederAPantallaUsuarios(Closure $next){...}
```

But It returns an error:  *Too few arguments to function UsuarioControllerTest::testUsuarioLogadoPuedeAccederAPantallaUsuarios(), 0 passed in C:\www\APPS\catsa\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php*

What's the solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the second code block where do you divine `$next` ?

Comment: @Mike, what? I dont' understand the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A `Closure` in PHP is simply a function, so you need to pass a function as the second argument of your `handle` method.

In the context of Laravel middleware, the `$next` function represent the full pipeline of steps that the `request` goes through.

Obviously you can't (and don't need to) execute this pipeline during a test. What you need is just a function that return some values that your can test in an assertion.

What you can do is something like this:

```php
//... setup code here


$middleware = new CheckRole();
$roles = ['role1', 'role2']; // change this with the desired roles
$result = $middleware->handle($request,function($request) {
    return 'success';
},$roles);

$this->assertEquals('success', $result);
```

So, what is happening here?

If everything goes as planned (the user has the required role), the `$next` closure is executed and it returns `success`; on the other hand, if the user doesn't have the required role, the code takes the other path and it returns a `RedirectResponse`.

Finally, the assertion checks if `success` is returned, and it reports a failure if that doesn't happen.